# Postgres will list my database, but it doesn't exist when I try connecting to it

Tags: postgresql, corruption, postgresql-11

From terminal, I

`sudo su postgres`

`psql`

`\l`:

```
postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 nwnx      | nwnx     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

But when trying to connect to it:

`\c nwnx`:

```
FATAL:  database "nwnx" does not exist
Previous connection kept
```

*quote_ident:*

```
postgres=# select quote_ident(datname) from pg_database;
 quote_ident 
-------------
 postgres
 template1
 template0
 nwnx
(4 rows)
```

*dumpall*:

```
pg_dumpall --schema-only | grep '\connect'
\connect template1
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "nwnx" failed: FATAL:  database "nwnx" does not exist
pg_dumpall: pg_dump failed on database "nwnx", exiting
```

*Creation script:*

```
pg_dumpall --schema-only | grep -i database
-- PostgreSQL database cluster dump
-- PostgreSQL database dump
-- Dumped from database version 11.5
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "nwnx" failed: FATAL:  database "nwnx" does not exist
pg_dumpall: pg_dump failed on database "nwnx", exiting
```

*Connecting as nwnx user*

```
$: psql postgres -U nwnx
psql (11.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=> \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "nwnx" via socket in "/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
postgres=> \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 nwnx      | nwnx     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres=> \c nwnx
FATAL:  database "nwnx" does not exist
Previous connection kept
```

**WORKING SOLUTION BY @laurenz-albe:**

*Showing all dbs*

```
postgres=# select oid, datname, datname::bytea FROM pg_database;
  oid  |  datname  |       datname        
-------+-----------+----------------------
 13121 | postgres  | \x706f737467726573
     1 | template1 | \x74656d706c61746531
 13120 | template0 | \x74656d706c61746530
 59515 | nwnx      | \x6e776e78
(4 rows)
```

*Checking if nwnx is omitted (had to use alias for datname)*

```
postgres=# SELECT oid, datname dn, datname::bytea FROM pg_database ORDER BY dn;
  oid  |    dn     |       datname        
-------+-----------+----------------------
 13121 | postgres  | \x706f737467726573
 13120 | template0 | \x74656d706c61746530
     1 | template1 | \x74656d706c61746531
(3 rows)
```

I followed the instructions from the solution and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Postgres version is 11.5

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong or whats going on?

Comment: Funny behavior... Try `pg_dumpall --schema-only | grep '\connect'` to check what PostgreSQL thinks about it itself. Or `pg_dumpall --schema-only | grep -i database` to find database creation script.

Comment: Is 'nwnx' your user name also?

Comment: @berkancetin: yes, its also the name of the user that I've connected with before

Comment: And do you have older intallations of PostgreSQL on your computer (most probably mac)?

Comment: With `sudo su postgres` you should be logged in as role `postgres`, and it seems you don't have access privileges with that (weird though as `postgres` should be a super user). Try changing your role to `nwnx` that is listed as owner of that database.

Comment: How this cluster was created? `psql`? `pg_restore`? `pg_basebackup`?`pg_upgrade`? `rsync`? Simple copy?

Comment: @Abelisto: I've had this database running for a while (like 9 months perhaps?). The database was created manually. It's been working fine up until yesterday when this weird stuff started happening.

Comment: @berkancetin: No, only this one installation (linux)

Comment: Can you check datoid in `pg_database` and see if the corresponding folder exists in `$PGDATA/base`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks a lot like database corruption, in particular like the index `pg_database_datname_index` (which is used in `GetDatabaseTuple()`) got corrupted.

To be sure, try the following:

```
-- should show all databases
SELECT oid, datname, datname::bytea FROM pg_database;
SET enable_seqscan = off;
-- should omit database "nwnx"
SELECT oid, datname, datname::bytea FROM pg_database ORDER BY datname;
```

If that confirms my suspicion, do the following:

- Stop the database with

  ```
  pg_ctl stop -m immediate -D /path/to/data/directory
  ```

  and take a cold backup of the database directory.
- Start the database with

  ```
  pg_ctl start -o -P -D /path/to/data/directory
  ```
- Connect to the database `postgres` and run

  ```
  REINDEX TABLE pg_database;
  ```
- Stop and restart PostgreSQL.

Now take a `pg_dumpall` from the cluster and restore it to a new cluster you create with `initdb`.

Answer (score -1):

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nwnx CASCADE;
will work

Comment: Thank you for commenting, and welcome to SO! This is unfortunately not a very good solution to this problem. First of all I very much would like to keep the data (if possible). Secondly, the problem seemed to be with a corruption in connecting to a _database_ named `nwnx` (not a table). 

This problem was (likely) caused by corruption, and @laurenz-albe's solution worked perfectly.